# Is it possible to install snaps (snapd) on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

Is there anyway to install snap on Debian? I have tried apt-get install snapd, with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `snapd` package is only available on [debian Stretch an debian Sid](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=snapd) , it cannot be installed through `apt`.

[Install snapd on Debian](https://snapcraft.io/docs/core/install-debian):

> On Debian snapd is available as part of the testing (currently ‘stretch’) and unstable (‘sid’) versions. It is currently not available in any stable version but will be soon

Comment: sorry, completely forgot that I left this open, thank you for your comment, and I did get it working on jessie

Comment: @Tyler Do you install it from source?

Comment: @Tyler Would you care to show us the commands you used?

Comment: it has been a while since I did it but if you give me a day to redo it to make sure I have everything correct I would be more than happy to

Comment: @Tyler can you edit your question by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` , please. I think you have a mixed source Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: It has been too long since I did this for me to show you the identical repo list, however I did not use any of the sources.list I used .deb archives